# Why ViewPager is slow

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using ViewPager to swipe between multiple images, but swiping between images is sluggish and not smooth although i only loaded few images. Here's my full code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

public static SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public static ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mSectionsPagerAdapter = new   SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment = new Page();
    args.putString(Page.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;

}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    Log.v("MBG", "getItemPosition");
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}

}
```

Page.java

```
public class Page extends Fragment {


public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
public Page() {
}

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page, container, false);
String index = getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

ImageView callImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(index, "drawable",  getActivity().getPackageName());

callImage.setImageResource(resID);

return rootView;

}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Prayers"


        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mahmoud.qaloun.Page">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/a1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But when i change this line of code

```
int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(index, "drawable",  getActivity().getPackageName());
```

to this:

```
int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("1", "drawable",  getActivity().getPackageName());
```

it works fine where "1" is an image stored in the resources folder "1.jpg"

Comment: What size of images?

Comment: I meant dimensions in pixels.

Answer (score 11):

Put

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

after `mViewPager.setAdapter();`

Replace `5` with the number of pages that are off screen, i.e. total number of pages minus 1.

This will make your `ViewPager` smooth.

The reason why `ViewPager` is slow without this is that any page which is off screen gets destroyed and is recreated every time you switch to that page. If you have time consuming code in your `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`, they're going to be executed on every page switch. If you set the  off screen page limit right, your Fragments will not be recreated every time you switch pages.

Answer (score 2):

In my case - I have more then **10 images** and each image have weight **more 800kb**, and I check this issue, and realy fine work if pass as a parameter ***3 page***

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Also if you store your images in `res/drawable` - rename `drawable` to `drawable-nodpi`, because *-nodpi* mean next

> These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale
>   resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current
>   screen's density.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. Please resize your image to smaller or required size. This will be a solution to your problem.